# python 3.3.2 print function wont run

Tags: python, printing, python-idle, python-3.3

I am a intro to python student working on a coding assignment. When I began to code I realized every time I tried to test the print () function Idle would not run my code. I typed it in exactly as follows:

```
def main():
     print("Enter 16-digit credit card number:")

     main()
```

It doesn't print anything. Did I do something very wrong, or is there something else going on?

Thanks y'all

Comment: Call to `main()` is not indented properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unindent your call to main.

```
def main():
    print("Enter 16-digit credit card number:")

main()
```

Comment: Yup, rookie mistake. Thank you for that